# What is the meaning of “Mensch” when used between friends or family members?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

I met a long-time couple recently, and I frequently heard the wife calling her husband *Mensch.*

As an example, at one point she asked

> Was ist das, Mensch?

and at another

> Ach, Du Mensch!

It was said in an exasperated, yet still clearly affectionate, manner.

(I’d seen it translated in other contexts — e.g., in a libretto for Alban Berg’s *Wozzeck* — as an insult; hence my confusion as to what the word means.)

Comment: Please take a look at [leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=mensch) - the translations with exclamation mark  (_Mensch!_ = Blimey, Gee, Gosh...) seems to be the translations you look for.

Comment: @knut: Not really—the "Mensch" didn't really seem to have that sense. It was used too often during the conversation, and it was always being addressed specifically to the husband.

Comment: @aeismail: I am pretty sure, that she didn't name her husband "Mensch". I guess it's more like a tic to use it that often.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "muasi" instead? Or maybe it was her husband's name which sounded like "mensch".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I never heard it that way and I can hardly imagine that this is just regional.

*Mensch* [is used as interjection](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mensch#Interjektion), especially when you're surprised about something.

It means gosh, gee, ... <sup>[LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Mensch)</sup>

Alternatively, you can say *Menschenskind(er)*. <sup>[LEO AGAIN](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=menschenskind)</sup>

Both sentences you gave sound odd to me. Maybe they fit in context, but I would rather use *Mensch* like this:

> *Mensch, daran hätte ich nicht gedacht*.

Note also [Mensch Meier](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mensch_Meier).

Comment: What about *dude*?

Comment: @Carlster Tell me. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Could be a tranlation for "Mensch" for some situations.

Comment: @Carlster Occasionally, yes. But I don't think it's the proper definition.

Comment: That's why I said "for some situations".

Comment: Yup. It's exactly the same kind of interjectional use that can be observed with *man!* in English. When it's overused by someone I can absolutely see a non-native speaker misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 7):

My German father used to use it with me regularly. Saying something like "you left the milk out again, mensh". I never really understood but, gosh and gee, ring true. There was definitely an air of affection to it.  He was from Berlin and born in the 1920s if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would say, that this is just a personal habit of your friend, it's neither used in regular German, nor did I ever heard it colloquially.

But I guess the best way to find out is asking her...

Comment: Might be a regional thing, it is quite commonly used in the Southern parts of Germany.

Comment: it is used quite often all over the republic...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is an expression of affection and surprise in it. It is used quite often as in "Pass doch auf, Mensch!", "Mensch, du hast Recht!" or "Ach, Mensch!". I would rate it as commonly used but colloquial.

There is also "Mensch, Meier!" which is used to express astonishment (Meier is a very common name in Germany)

Duden describes the usage of "Mensch" in aforementioned context as:

> als burschikose Anrede, oft auch ohne persönlichen Bezug in Ausrufen des Staunens, Erschreckens, der Bewunderung (salopp)

further examples listed in Duden:

> Mensch, da hast du aber Glück gehabt!
>
> Mensch ärgere dich nicht! (ein Gesellschaftsspiel)
>
> Mensch Meier! (salopp: Ausruf des Erstaunens)

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mensch_Lebewesen_Individuum#Bedeutungd